# Force chart to redraw or update Chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm creating a Chart.js Doughnut Chart, but i have two problems:
1. Chart doesn't update when i update the data source so data doesn't update.
2. The Chart is in a tab structure, and if i change tabs and then i go back to chart tab, it's gone, it doesn't redraw.

both problems would be fixed if i can force to redraw the chat, there's any way to do that?

```
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas baseChart height="220"
    [datasets]="productoChartData"
    [labels]="productoChartLabels"
    [options]="productoChartOptions"
    [legend]="productoChartLegend"
    [chartType]="productoChartType"
    [colors]="productoChartColors">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

and the TS

```
  public confirmadosChartLabels = ['Confirmados', 'Oportunidades'];
  public confirmadosChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    [0, 0]
  ];
  public confirmadosChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
  public confirmadosChartOptions: {
    responsive: false;
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right',
      labels: {
        boxWidth: 20,
        padding: 20,
        fontSize: 12
      }
    }
  };
  public confirmadosChartLegend = true;
  public donutColors = [{
    backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(75, 176, 138, 1)',
        'rgba(58, 129, 245, 1)']
    }];
```

and i update the datasource like this

```
const data: any = x.ResponseData;
this.confirmadosChartData[0][0] = data.Confirmadas;
this.confirmadosChartData[0][1] = data.Oportunidades;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try
   Please tried as mentioned bellow.

> var confirmadosChartData = this.confirmadosChartData;

than assign it value

> confirmadosChartData [0][0] =  data.Confirmadas; confirmadosChartData
>   [0][1] =  data. Oportunidades;

re assign it.

> this.confirmadosChartData =confirmadosChartData;

2. First try to empty array and than assign the value.

> this.confirmadosChartData = [] [];
>
> const data: any = x.ResponseData;
>
> this.confirmadosChartData[0][0] = data.Confirmadas;
>   this.confirmadosChartData[0][1] = data.Oportunidades;